# PHP curl returning bool(false) for localhost url but not external url. Curl works fine in command line

Tags: php, curl, localhost

When trying to access a file from localhost, using curl, all I get returned through var_dump is  `bool(false)`. However, if the `$url` is `example.com`, it works fine. The localhost server is set up and running fine so I can't see why this wouldn't work.

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost:81';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    var_dump(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);
```

`curl_error` returns: Curl error: Failed connect to localhost:81;

`http://localhost:81` works fine in my browser

Also, `curl http://localhost:81` works fine in command line

Comment: this is running on the same local host

Comment: Yes, it's running on the same local host